# $_GET value or eregi error?

Tags: php, get, eregi

I'm not sure where is my problem.  I've a script called with parameters (GET) like :

```
http://www.xxx.com?isms_restemsg=STOP&value=1
```

Here is my code :

```
$keyword_allowed = array("STOP", "");

$found_keyword = "N";
$keyword_cf = "";
for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    if (eregi($keyword_allowed[$i], $_GET["isms_restemsg"]))
    {
        $found_keyword = "Y";
        $keyword_cf = $keyword_allowed[$i];
    }
}
```

QUESTION : what happend when the url invoked is :

```
http://www.xxx.com?isms_restemsg=&value=1
```

In this case, what happend at the eregi instruction.

I'm asking this question because the $found_keyword="N", it should be "Y" Or is there an error ?

If yes can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `eregi()`, since it's [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php).

It doesn't even look as if you need regular expressions after all.

Give it a try with `stristr()` or even simple compare syntax:

```
if ($keyword_allowed[$i] == $_GET["isms_restemsg"])
```

(If you write this yourself you probably have control over the GET values as well.)

---

You can help yourself in such cases by echoing some debug output:

```
print_r($_GET);
for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    echo eregi($keyword_allowed[$i], $_GET["isms_restemsg"]));
}
```

Comment: Solution : if ($keyword_allowed[$i] == $_GET["isms_restemsg"])
thanks

Answer (score 2):

eregi is depreciated as of php 5.

Use [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) instead

```
 if (stristr($keyword_allowed[$i], $_GET["isms_restemsg"]))
```

Or better yet, [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$keyword_allowed = array("STOP", "");
$found_keyword = "N";

if(($keyword_c = array_search($_GET["isms_restemsg"], $keyword_allowed)) !== false) {
    $found_keyword = "Y";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as Martins told before, in this case I don't nee the eregi (deprecated) or stristr.  I don't check a part of the velue in the array, but the entire part.  but I keep it for future purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When the URL is like this

```
http://www.xxx.com?isms_restemsg=&value=1
```

Your `$_GET["isms_restemsg"]` is blank

hence  `if (eregi($keyword_allowed[$i], $_GET["isms_restemsg"]))`

second argument is passed as null in `eregi` function

`eregi` is deprecated stop using it replace with `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure yet, but there are probably other ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

First you could use a more specific regular expression to get rid of the loop. This checks for two alternatives, STOP and the empty string (this is probably what failed with your `eregi` test).

```
if (preg_match('/^(STOP | )$/ix', $_GET["isms_restemsg"], $r))
{
    $found_keyword = "Y";
    $keyword_cf = $r[0];
}
else {
    $found_keyword = "Y";
}
```

Or since you only need to check against two values:

```
if (in_array(strtoupper($_GET["isms_restemsg"]), array("STOP", "")) {
   $found_keyword = "Y";
}
```